# Azure B2C TrustFrameworkLocalization.xml and passing the attribute name on custom policy for errors

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I'm trying to pass the display name of all my fields to any of the inputs that fail when a user tries to sign up, but fails to for missing an input box?

The only Microsofts docs I could find was to just add the {0} and it would display on over the input.  But it just puts the actual the actual text of '{0}'

```
                <LocalizedString ElementType="UxElement" StringId="required_field">This 
                information is required {0} . </LocalizedString>
```

Am I missing a setting to activate this to pass the display names to the screen?

Thanks,
Adam

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s not possible to configure this, other than using custom JS.